# Requirements tools for PCB design?

Tags: pcb-design, testing

I'm writing requirements for our PCB designs, determining what clients want and what's possible to build. When requirements are finalized, I write tests for the same designs.

Right now, I'm doing it using plain old Word + lots of emailing back and forth. I've tried other solutions like Polarion ALM and Axiom, but found them *even harder* than Word + email. Is there any simple tool for writing requirements and tests?

Comment: The software world sometimes uses bug trackers for tracking requirements, which at least lets you auto-number them and integrate with revision control.

Answer (score 1):

I did a co-op at a company where I had to design a PCB. This company used Atlassian JIRA, an issue tracker used primarily by software engineers. However, I also used it to track my physical board requirements and such. It integrates with [Github](http://www.github.com) or [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/), both of which provide version control.

I would say your needs also depend on how many people are involved. JIRA is suitable if you have an entire team working on a project. If it's just you, someone else on the team, and the clients, then I would suggest Github or Bitbucket alone. At the very least, version control allows you to upload your requirements, schematics, or gerbers, update them, and track them. Everything would be shared amongst you and the client. It is definitely more efficient than emailing back and forth.

If you are not familiar with version control, I recommend a google search on what version control is, and also how to use version control with hardware projects. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, we already use a version control system. It gives us revisions and diffs but no tracing between requirements and test results. Is there any requirements management system specifically for hardware companies?